# Hierarchial deterministic wallets on Android

Tags: wallets, private-key, public-key, hd-wallets

Is there some implementation which lets me create `Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets` for Ethereum on Android ? I am looking for some library which lets me create the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experimented with [Consensys eth-lightwallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet). It makes use a 12-word seed to calculate private keys. You can probably look into its dependencies.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it in android ?

Comment: Your best bet would be to Google "BIP32 or BIP39 in Java" I guess.